# Extra slashes in path variable of File.Copy() or Directory.CreateDirectory() methods

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

When I use some `System.IO` methods, and "accidentally" put extra slashes (`\`) in the path variables, nothing special seems to happen.  No errors or warnings, and the code works as if just the right amount of slashes were present.

Example:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\\test");
File.Copy(@"C:\Users\Public\\Documents\test.txt", @"C:\Users\\Public\Documents\test\test.txt", true);
```

**So I'm wondering, is it potentially dangerous if the code above had extra slashes sometimes, or would it not matter one iota under any circumstances?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is quite resilient to this, haven't noticed a problem yet.

Take a look at [the snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773168/lnk2005-delete-already-defined-error-in-vc) in this thread.  Note the value of the _ACP_INCLUDE environment variable.  You have to scroll to the right to see:

> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\include;`

Afaik, a lot of machines that have VS2008 have this bad path, mine certainly does.  Nevertheless, it certainly can trip up your own code when you parse path strings.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not seem to mind, but why not make elegant code?

Comment: I would, but it's not always under my control!  So I was wondering if there would be any problems...

Comment: Everything is under your control.  `.Replace(@"\\","\");` for example.

Comment: Typos : should be `.Replace(@"\\",@"\");`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Windows "normalizes" the path structure before using it. To be safe, however, it is best to combine paths using:

```
Path.Combine(string1, string2);
```

instead of concatenating two strings.

Answer (score 0):

The case you should know,

```
CreateFileW(L"D:\\1\\test.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, CREATE_NEW, 0, 0);
// A file has been created.

CreateFileW(L"D:\\1\\test.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
// Of course, the file will be opened well.

CreateFileW(L"D:\\1\\\\test.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
// It works well too. Windows subsystem does canonicalize that.

CreateFileW(L"\\\\?\\D:\\1\\\\test.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
// '\\?\' prefix tell Windows "Don't touch my path, just send it to filesystem"
// So it will be failed.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#maxpath
I have no idea how .NET wraps this api. I guess Hans Passant might knows well about this. :)

Comment: FYI the \\ in the above code is an escape character that resolves to a single \.  That's C++ above, but in C#, `@"\"` = `"\\"`.